# About the discontinuity set of $\phi$ related to functions $f_1,...,f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis, continuity

If $f_1,...,f_n$ be n functions from a topological space  $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with discontinuity sets $D_1,...,D_n$ respectively.  Then about the discontinuity set of function $\phi$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\phi(x)=(f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$?

Comment: $\phi$ is continuous if and only if every $f_i$ is continuous. Therefore, you will have $D_1\times D_2\times\ldots \time D_n$ as the set of discontinuities of $\phi$.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the product set you show is not a subset of $X$.

Comment: Discontinuity set exactly equal to D_1x...xD_n or subset of D_1x...xD_n?